# Where is my fridge leaking from?

Tags: leak, refrigerator

I have a Whirlpool Gold fridge, model GI6FARXXB06. It's a French door design, with the freezer on bottom, as a drawer. It has an ice maker, and water / ice through the door.

For the last several weeks, I've noticed water seeping out from around the feet. It happens intermittently, maybe every couple of days. It's not a lot of water, probably a quart (liter) at a time before I notice and clean it up.

At the same time, a sheet of ice develops in the bottom of the freezer compartment, under the drawer. It gets to 1/2" (12 mm) thick in places, maybe 3/4" (18 mm). I suspect the water seeping out around the feet is this ice melting.

I see what looks like a small stream of frozen water in the back right of the freezer compartment, from the top to the bottom. I don't see any water leaking in the fridge compartment, either under the ice maker or under the filter housing, which might be the source of that stream though.

Where might my fridge be leaking from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds very similar to what I saw a few different places years ago with GE side-by-side. There was a drain hole in the bottom of the freezer that would drain to a pan underneath and (hopefully) evaporate. If the hole clogged up with ice then ice would collect in the bottom of the freezer and eventually melt in a big mess. Assuming it is a similar problem, it is probably NOT a leak but an issue with the defrost cycle and the normal small amount not draining out when/where it should.

Comment: @manassehkatz where would that hole normally be? I don't see anything on the bottom of the freezer compartment, but haven't removed any screws yet.

Comment: INSIDE: Towards the back of freezer, underneath the layer of ice. OUTSIDE: No idea, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

This model fridge like all fridges has a drain hole for the water to run out during the defrost cycle, with your fridge the drain hole is located behind the back wall in the freezer, in order to get to it the Wall has to be removed. You may need professional help. You have to remove the freezer door, The slide out drawer and ice maker,if it has one.The side rails need to be removed that hold up the slide out drawers.Now your ready to remove the back wall.now you Will have to melt the ice and remove it from the pan,once you find the drain hole you Will need to clean it out. Now you have to go behind the fridge,remove the back cover at the bottom and locate the drain tube, on the end off the tube you Will find what is called a duck bill, that needs to be pulled off and cleaned,once you do all that your ready to put it all back together.. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is that all?  Well, you did forget the last step: have a cold beer to celebrate when you're done, everything is back together, and it's all working.  Actually, if you mess everything up, just keep having cold beers until the repair guy gets there.  Or skip directly to calling the repair guy and drinking beer.  :-)